# eventListener adding extra text elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add a text element to an svg but its adding 3 of them. I started out adding the actual data using a bind method and so I thought that was the issue. But removing that and hardcoding the data didnt help. "d" is an Object here with 37 fields.

```
function handleMouseOver(d, i) {
// Add interactivity
let myLabel = d['ROBBERY'];
var svg = d3.select("svg");

// Use D3 to select element, change color and size
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(d['ROBBERY'])
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("id",i);
var textLabels = text
    .attr("x", w-50)

    .attr("y", h-30)
    .text(function () {
        return myLabel;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("fill", "red");
// Specify where to put label of text
```

}

......

```
.on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
```

there are no other text elements elements on the page.

I get 3 of these:

```
<text id="5" x="750" y="170" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="red">951</text>
<text id="5" x="750" y="170" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="red">951</text>
<text id="5" x="750" y="170" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="red">951</text>
```

Comment: What's the value of `d['ROBBERY']`?

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit, I had had the parenthesis in the eventhandler leftover. That didn't affect what is happening , but to answer your question the value of d['ROBBERY'] is 951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024259/d3-eventlistener-adding-extra-text-elements?noredirect=1#comment83027897_48024259), the value of `d['ROBBERY']` is `951`. So, what you're getting is the expected behaviour (hint: `951` has a length of `3`).

The `data()` method accepts **only** three things:

- An array;
- A function;
- Nothing.

So, when you pass a number (actually, a string) to `data()`, it will treat it as an array.

Have a look here:

```js
var body = d3.select("body")
var data = "951";
var p = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(String)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution:**

Don't use `data()` if you have just a single text element to append. Or, alternatively, wrap `d['ROBBERY']` in `[]`, turning it into an array:

```js
var body = d3.select("body")
var data = "951";
var p = body.selectAll(null)
  .data([data])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(String)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**PS**: The only reason that in your code you're getting `951` three times is that you're using...

```
.text(function () {
    return myLabel;
})
```

... to print the texts. If you used the data...

```
.text(function (d) {
    return d;
})
```

... you would have just `9`, `5` and `1`. Try it and you'll see.